# How to create managerID lookup hashtable

Tags: csv, powershell

I've had success in the past creating hash tables for looking up an exact match for one ID in a CSV, when looking it up on in another CSV, but what I'm trying to do must be very different? I have 1 CSV with everyone getting a unique LoginID and then a PositionID. Then in another column, I have "Reports to PositionID" with the manager PositionID there. I want to look up the manager's LoginID based on their PositionID, but have tried several ways unsuccessfully.

CSV example even when I remove the empty first row can't seem to get Bob's Person ID in cross reference to Reports to Position ID heading:

```
Person ID   Position ID Legal First Name Reports To Position ID
            YQM000051   DIANE           YQM000076
S9999991    YQM000052   CHARISSE        YQM000076
S9999992    YQM000052   CHARISSE        YQM000076
s9999993    YQM000052   CHARISSE        YQM000076
s9999994    YQM000076   Bob             YQM000071
```

Comment: This is the third time in a couple hours you asked basically the same question. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of hard to understand without seeing any examples but I imagine you could do something like the following:

```
#Imports CSV file as variable
$Csvfile = Import-Csv -Path "C:\SomePath\file.csv" -Delimiter "," 

#Change 1513 to the actual managers PositionID
$Csvfile | Where {$_.PositionID-eq "1513"} | Select -ExpandProperty LoginID
```

To test I created a quick csv with some random numbers:

```
loginID PositionID  ReportstoPositionid
1111    3654        1513
2222    1513        54123
3333    54123       16543564
4444    156413      156413
5555    16543564    3654
```

Then I decided that 1513 would be the managers position code and then ran the PowerShell commands above to get the loginid.

```
PS C:\> $Csvfile | Where {$_.PositionID -eq "1513"} | Select -ExpandProperty LoginID
2222
```

If you wanted to this all without a variable you could do the following:

```
PS C:\> Import-Csv -Path "C:\SomePath\file.csv" -Delimiter "," | Where {$_.PositionID -eq "1513"} | Select -ExpandProperty LoginID
2222
```

Lastly, you could remove the select statement if you wanted to see the full line in the csv file. Example:

```
loginID PositionID ReportsPositionid
------- ---------- -----------------
2222    1513       54123
```

Again, your questions was a little hard to understand but based on what I read here is what I came up with.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

After testing with the sample data, I believe you could use the following:

```
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\test1.csv" -Delimiter "," 
$Manager = $CSV1 | Where {$_.'Position ID' -eq 'YQM000076'} | Select -ExpandProperty "Legal First Name"

Write-Output "The Following Employees Report To $Manager :"

foreach ($Row in $CSV1)
    {
        if ($Row.'Reports to Position ID' -eq 'YQM000076')
            {
                Write-Output "$Row"
            }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
The Following Employees Report To Bob :
@{Person ID=; Position ID=YQM000051; Legal First Name=DIANE; Reports To Position ID=YQM000076}
@{Person ID=S9999991; Position ID=YQM000052; Legal First Name=CHARISSE; Reports To Position ID=YQM000076}
@{Person ID=S9999992; Position ID=YQM000052; Legal First Name=CHARISSE; Reports To Position ID=YQM000076}
@{Person ID=S9999993; Position ID=YQM000052; Legal First Name=CHARISSE; Reports To Position ID=YQM000076}
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, I didn't get any data back when I put in a ReportstoPositionID? I'm pulling from a large list with many managers and employees under some of them? My headers have spaces between the words? I'm using 'single' around or $Row.'Position ID'. Does that help?

Comment: hmm, I added spaces to the headers in my example and then changed  $_.PositionID to $_.'Position ID' and I received the same results I posted above. How similar is your csv to my example above? If possible, could you edit your question above with the first 5 lines of your csv including the headers? You can change the data, I would like to run some tests with everything in the exact same formatting. Also how is the csv saved? Is this a regular csv, csv (MS-DOS), or csv (Macintosh)?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? Run the following to find out:  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major                                                                      
Not sure if it matters yet but there could be a possibility that I am using something that was introduced in a newer version of PowerShell.

Comment: I'm on 4.0 and will edit the main question with sample headers and data. I can't seem to figure this out. Thx...

Comment: Ok, yeah at version 4 you definitely wouldn't see any issues with the commands above. Ill play with the sample data you post and Ill get back to you with what I find. Thanks

Comment: See my answer above, below **EDIT** section. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Still testing, but I think what I'm after is the Person ID of the manager? In AD, this would be the SamAccountName for us. Thx.

Comment: Hi Tyler, I think I found my problem in testing. I forgot to use the @{} empty array for the $PIDTable = @{}

 Import-csv $ADPcsv | ForEach-Object {
    $PIDTable[$_.'Position ID'] = $_
}

Comment: Marking your answer as it works now. Thx!